# cmd how to delete JPG file and keep only RAW

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I´m taking pictures with my mobile phone sometimes in JPG only, but sometimes in RAW. When shooting RAW, mobile phone actually stores two files (filename.jpg and filename.dng).
I would like to write a script which would search defined folder and delete all JPGs which have same filename like the DNGs (RAW).

Example - folder has following files:

```
IMG_20170625_105228.dng
IMG_20170625_105228.jpg
IMG_20170625_105326.jpg
IMG_20170625_105337.jpg
IMG_20170625_105350.dng
IMG_20170625_105350.jpg
```

Script should delete:

```
IMG_20170625_105228.jpg
IMG_20170625_105350.jpg
```

Comment: in CMD: `for %# in (*.dng) do del %~dpn#.jpg`. Use `%%#` instead of `%#` if called in a .bat script. You can do `echo del %~dpn#.jpg` first to see what would happen.

Comment: @Regejok I notice your repeated usage of the `#` as a for variable. While I know this is valid and in some use cases indispensable it may IMO confuse newbies as `help for` states `%variable  Specifies a single letter replaceable parameter`.

Comment: @LotPings You're right, I should stop using it. Got a weird habit of using `%#` as the main loop variable. Sometimes I even use `%$` for the second token. I'll use `%a` and `%b` from now on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the .dng files and if a like-named .jpg file exists, delete it. When you are satisfied that the correct files would be deleted, remove the `ECHO` from the `DEL` command.

```
PUSHD "C:\the\dir\containing\pics"

FOR /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%f IN (`DIR /B "*.dng"`) DO (
    IF EXIST "%%~nf.jpg" (ECHO DEL "%%~nf.jpg")
)

POPD
```

If, for whatever reason, you wanted to do this in PowerShell, you could do something like this. When the correct files are being removed, remove the `-WhatIf` from the `Remove-Item` command. I would be interested to hear from anyone about a better way to do this in PowerShell.

```
$picdir = 'C:\dir\path\to\pics'

Get-ChildItem -Path $picdir -File -Filter '*.dng' |
    Where-Object { Test-Path -Path "$($_.DirectoryName)/$($_.BaseName).jpg" -PathType Leaf } |
    Select-Object @{Name="Path";Expression={"$($_.DirectoryName)\$($_.BaseName).jpg"}} |
    Remove-Item -WhatIf
```